# Mysql Join query taking very long time or hanging the server

Tags: mysql

I have a query which is based on joins and getting data from 4 tables but the problem i am facing with this query is that when data gets larger like in millions this query don't work or takes very long to respond.

```
SELECT   tbl_vendormain.*, 
         tbl_deviceinfo.*, 
         tbl_deviceinfo.model# AS modelno, 
         tbl_eraserinfo.*, 
         timediff(tbl_eraserinfo.endtime, tbl_eraserinfo.starttime) AS eraserdiff, 
         tbl_vendorappresult.* 
FROM     (tbl_deviceinfo) 
JOIN     tbl_eraserinfo 
ON       tbl_eraserinfo.transactionid = tbl_deviceinfo.transactionid 
AND      tbl_eraserinfo.licenseid = tbl_deviceinfo.licenseid 
AND      tbl_eraserinfo.serial = tbl_deviceinfo.serial 
JOIN     tbl_vendorappresult 
ON       tbl_vendorappresult.transactionid = tbl_deviceinfo.transactionid 
AND      tbl_vendorappresult.licenseid = tbl_deviceinfo.licenseid 
AND      tbl_vendorappresult.serial = tbl_deviceinfo.serial 
JOIN     tbl_vendormain 
ON       tbl_vendormain.transactionid = tbl_deviceinfo.transactionid 
AND      tbl_vendormain.licenseid = tbl_deviceinfo.licenseid 
WHERE    date(tbl_deviceinfo.deviceupdateddate) BETWEEN  '2019-05-01'  AND '2019-05-31'
ORDER BY date(tbl_deviceinfo.deviceupdateddate) DESC
```

I tried indexing and partitioning but reponse time wasn't improved.I am using `MySQL 5.7.23` any help regarding this issue would be really appriciated Thanks.

Comment: Waaay too little information here for us to go on.

Comment: What else of information is required?

Comment: create indexes and try to use view.

Comment: HarshwardhanSharma thanks for you reponse Indexes are already created but how can we use views when the dates will be varying for each query?

Comment: @Awaisfiaz The table definitions, their indexes, how many rows are in each table at the very least.

Answer (score 0):

Given information is less. Still I will suggest. 
This completely depends on following things

> 1) Compute power (Your Server configuration/ RAM or hosted on Azure then DTU).
>
> 2) The query written. If data getting fetched is more it will take time.

Try to optimize your Query. As @Harshwardhan suggested use view or create indexes.

Comment: can we apply partitioning into views?

Answer (score -1):

if you are displaying response in the table, then use datatables. view will take the same amount of time.

for datatable you can use datatables.net
https://datatables.net/manual/installation

if response is not displaying in the table then implement the pagination, pagination will fetch limited number of row from the table, this is take less time then fetching the all the row at the same time.